# Where to find great resources on ASP.net Architecture, Web Site Architecture?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I've recently become heavily involved in a few projects that are going to work as company-wide intranet systems. They will basically be intranet websites, replacing older legacy systems that are desktop-based. I'd like to research the best ways to set-up these web site, or web application projects.

Most notably, I'm looking for:

1. Different architectures and the pros and cons of each. i.e. (Tiered architecuture, etc.)
2. Enterprise website programming practices, performance, caching, etc.
3. Optimized class architectures in .NET websites, web apps

I basically want some references and resources all pertaining to some of the best practices, ways in which I can optimize performance, layout a project to be easily maintainable and run at optimal levels of performance.

I did end up reading some of [Microsoft Application Architecture Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ce40e4e1-9838-4c89-a197-a373b2a60df2&displaylang=en), 2nd Edition, which is free online, Something along those lines would be helpful, although a little less cookie cutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many books to suggest thru they not directly tied with web development. I try to keep list small:

Start with: [7 Freely available E-Books/Guides I found essential for .NET Programmers and Architects](http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2010/09/7-freely-available-e-booksguides-i.html) By Anoop Madhusudanan

Framework Design Guidlines by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Adams

ASP.NET:

Utra-Fast ASP.NET (Build Ultra-Fast and Ultra-Scalable web sites using ASP.NET and SQL Server) by Richard Kiessig (APress)

Developing Large Web Applications by Kyle Loudon (O'Reilly)

Pro ASP.NET 4 CMS (Advanced Techniques for C# Developers using the .NET 4 Framework) by Alan Harris (APress)

And to understand some basics about how it works if you need it:

CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter

Concurrent Programming on Windows by Joe Duffy

There are many interesting books in design guidlines:

.NET Domain-Driven Design with C#: Problem - Design - Solution by Tim McCarthy (Wrox)

Debug It! Find, Repair, and Prevent Bugs in Your Code by Paul Butcher

or just interesting reading:

Beautiful Code - Leading Programmers Explain How They Think. Edited by Andy Oram & Greg Wilson

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should focus on is Design Patterns. Take a look at [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx) Design Pattern Framework. It's not free but ir has very good examples about enterbrise architecture programming. Also, [.Net Domain Driven Design With C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147563) is a hell of a book to see how to convert a legacy application to a state of the art application.
Good luck